# Server.createObject with Persist.Mailsender error

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am having a problem with this line `Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")` in my code. This code used to work fine before. All of a sudden it started throwing an error stating the create object failed. Can anyone suggest a work around?

```
    Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")" 
                ' enter valid SMTP host
    Mail.Host =  "smtpeu1-css.shell.com"
    Mail.From =  "SHIPLocalHost@shell.com"
    Mail.FromName = "SHIPLocalHost@shell.com"

    Mail.AddAddress  defaultTestEmail, defaultTestEmailName
    'If(len(emailCCEmail)>0)Then
        'Mail.AddAddress   defaultTestEmailCC , defaultTestEmailCCName
    'End If
    Mail.Subject = subject
    Mail.IsHTML = True
    'send an email for SSR
    Mail.Body= mailbody
    'Mail.AddAttachment "C:\Apps\SHIP from PROD\ship\ship\UploadedFiles\" & strFileName
    Mail.AddAttachment FilePath
    Mail.Send
```

Comment: Can you post the error message that you are receiving?

Comment: @Migul-F : Here is the error message on the very first line  where createobject is used:                                                                                    Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' 

Server.CreateObject Failed 

/pages/upload.asp, line 129 

800401f3

Comment: Did you see this? [Why do I get 800401F3 / 800A01AD errors?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/components/why-do-i-get-800401f3/800a01ad-errors.html)  Has anything changed on your server before this started happening (patches, upgrade, etc)?

Comment: @Miguel-F : thanks for the link.not sure if any auto upgradation has happened in my system.But going by the links I would like to know since my code  uses aspmail feature.What is the way to get the dll for asp mail and how to register it?

Comment: http://www.aspemail.com/

Comment: It is free for 30 days.  If you dont want to pay for the advanced features of asp email you can use CDOSYS to send email.

Comment: You pretty much need to find aspemail.dll somewhere in the Net or in your disk archives, and run "regsvr32 aspemail" command. This should take care of it.