# Internal Server Error with VB script

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to send an email with VB script/ASP (I don't normally use this language but this is what the site is built in), and it is throwing a 500 error.

I'm not seeing what I did wrong. Everything looks like it should execute to me. Any ideas?

```
<%
dim name
dim from
dim company
dim phone
dim zip
dim message
dim areas

name = Request.Form("name")
from = Request.Form("from")
company = Request.Form("company")
phone = Request.Form("phone")
zip = Request.Form("zip")
areas = Request.Form("areas")
message = Request.Form("message")


Dim Mail, strHost
Dim strSubject, strBody, strPath

strHost = "localhost"

Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")

Mail.Host = strHost
Mail.From = "cphelps@client.com"
Mail.FromName = "Client Name"
Mail.AddAddress "cphelps@client.com"
If Not InStr(from, "domain.com") Then Mail.AddBcc "cphelps@client.com"
Mail.Subject = name & " sent a request"
Mail.Body = name & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &_ 
     "Name:" & name & vbCrLf &_ 
     "Company: " & company & vbCrLf &_ 
     "From: " & from & vbCrLf &_ 
     "Phone: " & phone & vbCrLf &_ 
     "Zip Code: " & zip & vbCrLf &_ 
     "Message: " & message & vbCrLf &_ 

Mail.Send
Response.Redirect("jlg_thank_you.asp")

set Mail = nothing

%>
```

Comment: Do you have more information on the error ? If you disable IE's friendly error messages, perhaps you'll have a more meaningful error. Make sure "aspemail.dll" is properly registered on the server running the script.

Comment: It isn't a problem in the script?

Comment: I suspect an error is happening in the CreateObject line. Disable IE'S friendly error messages and ASP should tell you on which line it's crashes exactly.

Comment: Good. Now, tell us the line number at which the script bombs.

Comment: In Firefox, all it says is: 
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. I don't ever use VB, or ASP.NET, and I have no idea why I was even assigned this project. I'm typically Linux environments only.

Comment: Then if Firefox is not chatty enough, like I said, browse the script with IE with friendly message turned off and you'll get the line #.

Comment: Turned off IE friendly error messages. Same error is displayed.

Comment: Are you even able to run a "Hello World" script on this box ?

Comment: Yes, hello world works.

Comment: How about "Custom Errors" in IIS ? Anything funky in there ? Perhaps a custom error page is preventing you from seeing the error.

Comment: I checked the logs and got this: 2013-12-18 21:18:59 69.39.80.16 POST /jlg_contact_email.asp |24|800a01ad|ActiveX_component_can't_create_object 80 CLIENTDEV\client-staging 69.39.80.29 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:25.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/25.0 500 0 0 209

Comment: Check my answer. I'm pretty sure that'll solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I noticed is that you are missing an `End If` in the code sample provided.

I disabled Friendly error messages and I attempted to run the code and got this error:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' 
Server.CreateObject Failed 
/test.asp, line 26 
800401f3
```

On researching this error I found someone with a similar problem:

[Server.createObject with Persist.Mailsender error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418391/server-createobject-with-persist-mailsender-error)

They suggested that its a missing dll problem.

For my projects I have used `Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")`

Here is an example of my code:

```
Set mail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
mail.To = varTo
mail.From = varFrom
mail.Subject = varSubject
mail.HTMLBody = varBody
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.domain.com"
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
mail.Configuration.Fields.Update
mail.Send
```

Comment: Do you have the Persits.MailSender (aspemail.dll) assembly registered on your machine ? If not, of course the CreateObject will fail...

Comment: FYI...the if then statement there is valid...it doesn't need the end if IF you have the "then" statement on the same line. Coding shortcut that is just asking for trouble ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you downloaded the latest version of [`ASPEmail`](http://www.aspemail.com/) and that it is present on the server running the script.

Also, register it using this command line:

```
regsvr32 c:\path\aspemail.dll
```

Comment: What is the user running the application pool of the website ? Can you grant it local admin rights temporarily to see if it can create objects?